# Window Type Effect on Pwelch vs ShortTimeFFT PSD Result?

Tags: matlab, python, power-spectral-density, stft

I am trying to make sure I understand the output scaling of pwelch. I am using the PWelch function to compute the PSD of a signal and I have manually computed the PSD from an STFT output. The results are equivalent when I use a rectangular (boxcar) window, but if I use another window (Hann) the PSD outputs are no longer equivalent. Why is this? I’ve tried this in both Matlab and Python, so my lack of understanding must be on the theory of the pwelch method and not some programming bug.

I have attached code the demonstrates the effect in both Python and Matlab. Uncomment the hann window lines and comment the boxcar/rectwin lines to see the difference.

Much Thanks,
Michael

MATLAB Example

```
timeDur = 2;
Fs = 3750;
dt = 1/Fs; 
nSamps = Fs * timeDur;
complexData = randn(nSamps,1) + 1j*randn(nSamps,1);

tWind = 0.02;
nWind = floor(tWind * Fs);
nOvlp = floor(tWind * Fs * 1/2);

%[S, f_stft, t_stft] = stft(complexData, Fs, 'Window', hann(nWind),'OverlapLength',nOvlp);
[S, f_stft, t_stft] = stft(complexData, Fs, 'Window', rectwin(nWind),'OverlapLength',nOvlp);
Pxx_stft = mean( dt^2/tWind * abs(S).^2,2);

%[Pxx_pwelch,f_pwelch ] = pwelch(complexData,hann(nWind),nOvlp,f_stft,Fs);
[Pxx_pwelch,f_pwelch ] = pwelch(complexData,rectwin(nWind),nOvlp,f_stft,Fs);

figure
plot(f_pwelch, 10*log10(Pxx_pwelch), '-'); hold on
plot(f_stft,   10*log10(Pxx_stft), '--')
```

PYTHON Example

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib as npmatlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fftshift
from scipy.fft import fft
from scipy.fft import fftfreq
from scipy import signal
import math
from scipy.signal import ShortTimeFFT
from scipy.signal.windows import hann
from scipy.signal.windows import boxcar

timeDur = 2
Fs = 3750
dt = 1/Fs; 
nSamps = Fs * timeDur
complexData = np.random.randn(nSamps) + 1j*np.random.randn(nSamps)

tWind = 0.02
nWind = math.floor(tWind * Fs)
nOvlp = math.floor(tWind * Fs * 1/2)

#USE SCIPY TO COMPUTE PSD VIA WELCH'S METHOD
#f, Pxx = signal.welch(complexData, Fs, window='hann', nperseg=nWind, noverlap=nOvlp,scaling='density',return_onesided=False,detrend=False)
f, Pxx = signal.welch(complexData, Fs, window='boxcar', nperseg=nWind, noverlap=nOvlp,scaling='density',return_onesided=False,detrend=False)

#MANUALLY COMPUTE POWER SPECTRAL DENSITY VIA WELCH'S METHOD
nSamps = np.size(complexData)
#window = hann(nWind);
window = boxcar(nWind);
STF    = ShortTimeFFT(window,  hop = nWind-nOvlp, fs=Fs, fft_mode='twosided')
S      = STF.stft(complexData)
Pxx_stft = dt**2/tWind * np.mean(np.abs(S)**2, axis=1)

figPSD, axPSD   = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, layout='constrained')
axPSD.plot(fftshift(f), fftshift(10*np.log10( Pxx )))
axPSD.plot(fftshift(STF.f), fftshift(10*np.log10( Pxx_stft ), axes=0), '--')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct scaling for the complex PSD is:

$$\frac{|X|^2}{f_s \times S} \quad \texttt{with} \quad S =
   \sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1} w_i^2$$ where $w_i$ are the window samples:

```matlab
window = hann(nWind);
win_scaling = sum(window.^2);

[S, f_stft, t_stft] = stft(complexData, Fs, 'Window', window,'OverlapLength',nOvlp);
Pxx_stft = mean( abs(S).^2/(win_scaling*Fs),2);
```

### [image]

In case you wonder why your original scaling worked for the rectangular window and not other windows, consider that `tWind = nWind/Fs`, so `dt^2/tWind * abs(S).^2` is equivalent to:

`abs(S).^2 * Fs/ (Fs^2 * nWind) = abs(S).^2 / (Fs * nWind)` and for a rectangular window, `nWind = win_scaling`

Comment: Thanks so much!